# How to fix button width in button group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to prevent buttons to resize on hover? I want them to stay fixed but different widths

```
.btn-group.simple-btn-group role="group"
  button.btn.btn-default type="button" Some
  button.btn.btn-default type="button" Something 

.simple-btn-group 
 .btn:hover
   font-weight: bold
```

Comment: just change the css on hover event.Any jsfiddle or demo?

Comment: simply. don't write anything on hover.

Comment: `font-weight: bold` will change the width of the text. Remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.simple-btn-group 
 .btn:hover
   font-weight: bold
```

The bold value increases the text size to certain extent that causes the button to expand. Remove the property `font-weight`

**If you need the bold text then go with below**

In order to have a fixed width on both normal and hover state, set a width of the button which is higher than the button in two states.

```
.simple-btn-group 
 .btn
  width: 55px; // Make sure this is higher than hover state too
```